# Simple pendulum and planet mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, gravity, harmonic-oscillator, kinematics

A simple pendulum, $20cm$ in length, has the period of $2.7s$ on a certain planet. Find the mass of the planet if its diameter is $18000km$. $G=6.67\times10^{-11}Nm^2/kg^2 $

I have no idea how to get to the solution except for the formula 
$$g=(GM)/(R^2) $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next thing you'll need is time period of a simple pendulum [$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{g}}$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum)